# Método de Newton en C con funciones de entrada multiparamétricas

Tags: c

últimamente estoy metido de cabeza en la programación de un programa de optimización. En varias partes del código necesito hacer interaciones que se resolverían con un método tipo Newton, entonces me he planteando la posibilidad de hacer una función de pasándole tú una función, y un valor inicial te de los ceros de la función, el problema es que como voy a tener una gran variedad de funciones de entrada, las cuales dependen de varios parámetros (A parte de la variable).

Es decir, se resolver : `y = x^2 + 1`

Pero quiero hacer una función que resuelva :

```
y = x^2 + c + d
```

o

```
y = x^2 + 1 + k +2*x
```

Tengo claro de que en caso de que mi función solo dependiera de X o de si supiera de antemano cuales son los parámetros, se haría de esta manera :

#### Método de Newton

```
double f_zero( double(*f)(double),double *x0,double *TOL,int *maxiter){

  double deriv,xn,xn1,x_l,x_r;
  int i=1;

  xn = *x0;

  while(i<=*maxiter){
    x_r = xn + *TOL;
    x_l = xn - *TOL;
    deriv = 0.5*(f(x_r)-f(x_l))/(*TOL);
    xn1 = xn - f(xn)/deriv;
    xn = xn1;
    i++;
  }

  return xn;
}
```

A alguien se le ocurre algo ?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: No entiendo el problema... la función `f_zero()` que has puesto ya es lo bastante genérica como para hallarte el cero de cualquier función de x que le pases, ya que el primer argumento es la función en cuestión. Dices "si mi función sólo dependiera de X", pero es que los dos ejemplos que has puesto sólo dependen de x

Comment: Si pero hay otros parámetros que hay que pasarle a la función como c y d (por ejemplo) no ?

Comment: Pero `c` y `d` no son variables con respecto a los cuales la función varíe, no? Entonces entiendo que son constantes para una función dada y por tanto podrían estar "hardcoded" en la propia función.

Comment: Si eso es, no sabia eso de hardcoded, en que consiste ?

Comment: Simplemente que son números constantes que no se reciben como parámetro. Por ejemplo: `float func1(float x) { return (x^2 + 2 + 4); }` implementaría la primera función que pusiste como ejemplo, para el caso c=2, d=4.

Comment: Ahhh vale si si, se a que te refieres, pero en mi caso necesito que c y d se reciban como parámetros. Quizás no me expliqué bien perdón.

Comment: Si el número de esos parámetros extras que vas a recibir es siempre el mismo, puedes simplemente añadirlos como parte de la declaración del puntero a función que estás recibiendo. Si en cada caso puede ser diferente, una solución puede ser que recibas además de la x un array con los diferentes coeficientes. Así siempre tienes sólo dos parámetros (la x y el array), pero cada función usará más o menos elementos de ese array según lo que necesite.

Comment: Muy buena idea, muchas gracias !!!   : )

Comment: La declaración entonces sería : `double f_zero( double(*f, *parameters)(double), double *x0,double *TOL,int *maxiter){...}` ??

Comment: No: `double f_zero( double (*f)(double, double*), double *x0,double *TOL,int *maxiter)`. Lo que va entre paréntesis tras `(*f)` son los tipos de los parámetros de la función `f`.

Comment: Un millón de gracias por tus amables consejos !